# Cannot see global asset publisher's template in site scope

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created global template for asset publisher. I placed asset publisher into some site's page. When I want to change asset publisher's template for displaying its content there isn't my global template for selection, why?

thanks.
Patrik

Comment: How did you create your global template?

Comment: through control panel. I opened control panel, select page templates, create new page template, added asset publisher into page and then openned configuration of this portlet. from configuration I have created this tempalte.

Comment: Did you use the `page template` to create the actual site-page with the asset-publisher portlet? If not then it would not work. The publisher-template is local to the page-template and its not global.

Comment: Yes, I created page template, added asset publisher to this template and through asset publisher's configuration I created asset publisher's template. If this is not proper way how to create global asset publisher template so which is the correct way? Can you write me step by step instructions how can I create global asset publisher template? I am using liferay 6.2 GA2